# getRowCount() method on viewPanel control & database full text index error

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I have simple code to count the rows in view panel control: 
getComponent("viewPanel1").getRowCount()

Error calling method 'getRowCount()' on java class 'com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel'

Stack trace shows the details as below:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException: Script interpreter error, line=1, col=64: Error calling method 'getRowCount()' on java class 'com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel'
Caused by: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Notes error: The full text index for this database is in use
Caused by: NotesException: Notes error: The full text index for this database is in use
   at lotus.domino.local.View.FTSearchSorted(Unknown Source)
```

Any quick solution to avoid these errors on server?

Comment: Put the full text indexer in it's own thread will cure some FT problems. notes.ini: Update_Fulltext_Thread=1

Answer (score 0):

This is, in fact, a server issue. Take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/535121/the-full-text-index-for-this-database-is-in-use-on-virtual-server-not-on-dedi) or google it to fine-tune your server.